# Подскажите как расположить элемент на dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

У меня есть dataGridView, где подключена таблица, одно из полей типа Дата. 
Я хочу сделать так, что бы при клике на это поле появлялся элемент выбора даты, dateTimePicker. Именно что бы он был на grid'e, рядом с полем, как на картинке (это в Access так отображается). 
Сам DataGridView не предлагает ни чего что можно было бы использовать для задания положения календаря. Есть какие-нибудь мысли как такое сделать?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. На событие `CellClick` у `DGV` повесьте код, вычисляющий координаты `Cell`.

   ```
   var cellRectangle = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(1, 1, true);
   // Can create Points using the Rectangle if you want.
   Console.WriteLine("Top Left     x:{0}\t y:{1}", cellRectangle.Left, cellRectangle.Top);
   Console.WriteLine("Bottom Right x:{0}\t y:{1}", cellRectangle.Right, cellRectangle.Bottom);
   ```
2. В свойство `dgv.Controls` добавьте ваш `DateTimePicker`.
3. Задайте свойству `DateTimePicker.Location` координаты, найденные на шаге 1.
4. Вызывайте ваш пиккер `DateTimePicker.Show();`

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Comment: @KarpovBoris в таком случае помечайте как ответ

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, форумом не давно пользуюсь.

Answer (score 0):

**Не советую Вам этого делать**, это костыль, и куча лишнего кода.
Вам придется постоянно отлавливать отрисовку и корректировать положение и видимость контрола.
Самый правильный путь переопределить базовый тип ячейки семейства DataGridView.
Если нет желания реализовывать его полностью предлагаю рассмотреть Вам менее костыльный вариант.

```
public partial class DateTimePickeCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {
        public DateTimePicker pic;   
        readonly DataGridView dataGridView;//Особенность моего кастомного грида (Вам можно не передавать и далее по коду  this.DataGridView)
        public DateTimePickeCell(DataGridView _dataGridView) : base()
        {
            dataGridView = _dataGridView;          
        }

        protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged()//Очень удобное для нас событие вызывается при заполнении и при обновлении (моя особенность, мой грид может вызыватся безконечно и иметь разную структуру данных)
        {
            base.OnDataGridViewChanged();
            if (pic == null)
            {
                pic = new DateTimePicker() { Name = "1",   Font = dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font, BackColor = dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor, ForeColor = dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor };
                dataGridView.Controls.Add(pic);
                pic.BringToFront();
            }
            else//если pic != null значит OnDataGridViewChanged вызывается с намеринием обновить данные dataGridView, возможно с иной структурой.         
                dataGridView.Controls.Remove(pic);//удалим с контрола dataGridView. 
        }
        
        protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
        {
            var rec = cellBounds;
            pic.Location = rec.Location;// new Point(rec.Location.X, rec.Location.Y);
            pic.Size = rec.Size;//new Size(rec.Size.Width, rec.Size.Height);
            base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
        }

    }
}

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]