# Создание своего контрола и внедрение в столбец dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, usercontrol

Создание своего контрола и внедрение в столбец dataGridView.
Создал свой контрол с ComboBox и несколько кнопок.
Как внедрить этот контрол в столбец dataGridView.
Это сделано с целью выбора из базы даных какого нибудь поля и выполнения каких то  действий.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Customizing the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/customizing-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подскажите как расположить элемент на dataGridView](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645071/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-datagridview)

Answer (score 1):

**Не советую Вам этого делать, это возможно но, это костыль**, и куча лишнего кода.
Вам придется постоянно отлавливать отрисовку и корректировать положение и видимость контрола.
Самый правильный путь переопределить базовый тип ячейки семейства DataGridView.
Если нет желания реализовывать его полностью предлагаю рассмотреть Вам менее костыльный вариант.

```
public partial class ComboBoxEx : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
{
    public Button btn; //Кнопочек можите накить сколько душе угодно это для примера
    const int MIXING = 1;//Небольшая коректировка положения кнопки

    readonly DataGridView dataGridView;//Особенность моего кастомного грида (Вам можно не передавать и далее по коду  this.DataGridView)
    public ComboBoxEx(DataGridView _dataGridView) : base()
    {
        dataGridView = _dataGridView;          
    }

    protected override void OnDataGridViewChanged()//Очень удобное для нас событие вызывается при заполнении и при обновлении (моя особенность, мой грид может вызыватся безконечно и иметь разную структуру данных)
    {
        base.OnDataGridViewChanged();
        if (btn == null)
        {
            btn = new Button() { Name = "1", Text = "+", TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Font = dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.Font, BackColor = dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor, ForeColor = dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor, FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System };
            dataGridView.Controls.Add(btn);
            btn.BringToFront();

            btn.Click += (e, s) =>
            {
                var obj = (Button)e;
            };
        }
        else//если btn != null значит OnDataGridViewChanged вызывается с намеринием обновить данные dataGridView, возможно с иной структурой.         
            dataGridView.Controls.Remove(btn);//удалим копку с контрола dataGridView. 
    }
    
    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates elementState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        var rec = cellBounds;
        int width = rec.Size.Height;//Ширина кнопки это выcоса ячейки(итог квадрат)
        btn.Location = new Point(rec.Location.X + rec.Size.Width - width, rec.Location.Y - MIXING);
        btn.Size = new Size(width, rec.Size.Height + MIXING);
        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, elementState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);
    }

}
```

[image]